# Помогите распарсить строку

Tags: php

Требуется извлечь из всех узлов `JSON`-строки значения с идентификатором `"text"` с целью собрать на выходе выражение (предложение).

Вопрос: как перебрать все элементы данной `JSON`-строки?

```
{
  "language": "ru",
  "textAngle": 0.0,
  "orientation": "Up",
  "regions": [
    {
      "boundingBox": "42,12,596,465",
      "lines": [
        {
          "boundingBox": "42,12,557,49",
          "words": [
            {
              "boundingBox": "42,13,64,41",
              "text": "ты"
            },
            {
              "boundingBox": "120,13,175,48",
              "text": "БУДЕШЬ"
            },
            {
              "boundingBox": "309,12,198,43",
              "text": "визжать"
            },
            {
              "boundingBox": "521,13,78,41",
              "text": "как"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "boundingBox": "180,71,286,49",
          "words": [
            {
              "boundingBox": "180,71,286,49",
              "text": "МАНДРАГОРА,"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "boundingBox": "70,422,506,49",
          "words": [
            {
              "boundingBox": "70,422,135,49",
              "text": "когда"
            },
            {
              "boundingBox": "216,422,235,43",
              "text": "ПОЛУЧИШЬ"
            },
            {
              "boundingBox": "465,423,111,41",
              "text": "мня"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "boundingBox": "569,465,69,12",
          "words": [
            {
              "boundingBox": "569,465,54,12",
              "text": "riSOVach."
            },
            {
              "boundingBox": "625,469,13,7",
              "text": "ru"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: перебери циклом сначала lines, а затем words. в Чем проблема?

Comment: Используйте `$words[] = array_walk_recursive(function ($value, $key){ if ($key == 'text'){ return $value; } }); echo implode(' ', $words);`

Answer (score 2):

```
$json_string = '{
    "language":"ru",
            "textAngle":0.0,
            "orientation":"Up",
            "regions":[
    {
        "boundingBox":"42,12,596,465",
            "lines":[
        {
            "boundingBox":"42,12,557,49",
                "words":[
            {
                "boundingBox":"42,13,64,41",
                    "text":"ты"
            },
            {
                "boundingBox":"120,13,175,48",
                    "text":"БУДЕШЬ"
            },
            {
                "boundingBox":"309,12,198,43",
                    "text":"визжать"
            },
            {
                "boundingBox":"521,13,78,41",
                    "text":"как"
            }
            ]
        },
        {
            "boundingBox":"180,71,286,49",
                "words":[
            {
                "boundingBox":"180,71,286,49",
                    "text":"МАНДРАГОРА,"
            }
            ]
        },
        {
            "boundingBox":"70,422,506,49",
                "words":[
            {
                "boundingBox":"70,422,135,49",
                    "text":"когда"
            },
            {
                "boundingBox":"216,422,235,43",
                    "text":"ПОЛУЧИШЬ"
            },
            {
                "boundingBox":"465,423,111,41",
                    "text":"мня"
            }
            ]
        },
        {
            "boundingBox":"569,465,69,12",
                "words":[
            {
                "boundingBox":"569,465,54,12",
                    "text":"riSOVach."
            },
            {
                "boundingBox":"625,469,13,7",
                    "text":"ru"
            }
            ]
        }
        ]
    }
    ]
}';

$obj=json_decode($json_string);
```

Решение №1 - не рекомендуемое, для разминки с циклом `for`

```
 for ($n = 0; $n < count($obj->regions); $n++) {
    for ($j = 0; $j < count($obj->regions[$n]->lines); $j++) {
       for ($i = 0; $i < count($obj->regions[$n]->lines[$j]->words); $i++) {
          echo $obj->regions[$n]->lines[$j]->words[$i]->text." ";
       }
    }
 }
```

Решение №2 - рекомендуемое

```
foreach($obj->regions as $regions) {
     foreach($regions->lines as $lines) {
            foreach($lines->words as $words) {
                  echo $words->text . " ";
            }
     }
}
```

Comment: может для общего развития участников не столь "зубастых" (в хорошем смысле) минусы будут сопровождаться конкретикой в комментариях?

Comment: Потому что есть foreach и array_values

Comment: @ilyaplot за коммент спасибо, полемику раздувать не настроен, но ведь решение рабочее. Не все же могут знать супер пупер идеальное решение.

Comment: Возможно, не совсем рабочее `regions[0]` обработает только первый ключ.

Comment: поправил, спасибо

Comment: Ок, а теперь представьте, что lines не содержит words или в одном из элементов отсутствует text. Все равно придете к foreach, а в рамках оптимизации производительности и уменьшения количества кода к array_values. Можно написать любую функцию на 300 строк длиннее, при этом она будет работать, но за такой код никто спасибо не скажет.